# Replacing a placeholder term with a session variable value in taxonomy filter

Tags: taxonomy, hooks, session

I have in my themes some code which will set a session variable. For the sake of example, it's a geolocation routine which will set to either USA, UK or ROW, resulting in:

```
$_SESSION['region'] = 'USA';
```

and I have a custom taxonomy of 'regionok' which any or all of the same terms are set.

I wish to use the session variable value as the taxonomy term to filter on.

The cleanest solution I can imagine would be to have a filter hook in my functions.php which would replace the placeholder term 'auto-region' with the session value before each query is executed. That way I can use widget plugins without having to hack them - I would just use the placeholder term in configuration. However, I don't know what the relevant hook would be.

(Other use cases would be session variables for family filter, referrer, etc. The geolocation example is entirely incidental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply this term filter to all queries on the site, then you'll want to use the 'parse_query' action.  This action will accept the WP_Query instance as a parameter, which will allow you to add a term filter based on the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: Yep. That works. Ta.